# Google Drive Operations With XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am using web workers to perform certain operation in google drive i have found solution for delete file or folder from XMLHttpRequest but i still need to perform rename, search, upload etc.

My question is there any way we can convert clietn rest call to XMLHttpRequest.

For delete i have doen something like this.

```
var obj = {
    method : "DELETE",
    url : DRIVE_HOME_URL +"/"+ fileId +'?key='+object.apiKey,
    accessToken : object.accessToken
}
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open(object.method, object.url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + object.accessToken);
if(object.headers){
    for (var key in object.headers) {
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(key, object.headers[key]);
    }
}
xmlhttp.onload = function(xhr) {
    if (callback) {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.onerror = function(data) {
    if (errorCallback) {
        errorCallback(data);
    }
};
if(object.data){
    xmlhttp.send(object.data);
} else {
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: For all google API's, you should send REST requests to access API's. For this, you can use many languages which are supported by google. check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js for java script client with sample code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i know i should use Api but i want to use Web workers, the problem is web worker doesn't have access to window object and client rest API need window object.That is why i want to use XMLHttpRequest. I am able to delete files by XMLHttpRequest but i don't how to send request for other operations.